# PHP: Removing an attribute from a DOMNode object

Tags: php, dom

I've got a `DOMNode` object that has some attributes. `$Node->attributes` is a `DOMNamedNodeMap`, which has no methods for removing one of the entries in the map. The `DOMNode` class also has no methods for removing attributes from an element.  I've looked through a number of the other related classes and none of them seem to provide a mechanism for removing an attribute node from its parent.

`DOMNode::removeChild` doesn't work; it throws a "Not found error" if I pass a `DOMAttr` object to it.

Aside from constructing a new `DOMNamedNodeMap` and adding all the attributes to it *except* the one I don't want... any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got a `DOMNode` that has some attributes, it must be a `DOMElement`. In which case you should be able to call `removeAttribute/removeAttributeNS/removeAttributeNode` on it.

It is somewhat curious that PHP's `DOMNamedNodeMap` documents `getNamedItem[NS]` but does not acknowledge the existence `setNamedItem[NS]` and `removeNamedItem[NS]`, which would have been another way of doing it.

`DOMNode::removeChild` can't work because a `DOMAttr` is not a child of another `DOMNode; ‘attributes’` is a separate space to `childNodes`. You also can't create a new `NamedNodeMap` on its own to write to `DOMNode::attributes`, as that's a read-only property.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.  I hadn't yet grokked that the DOMNode would also be a DOMElement.  That's what I get for not using ReflectionClass::export() enough :)